# Python: Access a list in a class with properties or custom methods

Tags: python, list, class, properties, getter-setter

I have the following class:

```
def Interface:
    def __init__(self, vlan, zone, address):
        self.vlan = vlan
        self.zone = zone
        self.__address = []
        for i in address:
            self.__address.append(ipaddress.IPv4Interface(i))
```

An Interface instance could never have more than one zone and vlan, but could have 1+ addresses.
Up to now the address parameter is a list with one or more addresses as items.

So this is my first question: Is it good practice to use a list as argument?

---

Currently i think about how to access the address variable:

1. Use properties

   I could use properties @address.set for append an address, @address.del for delete one specific address and @address to get *all* addresses as list.

   What i don't like with this approach is:

   - No way in the future (imho) to extend this with functions like a 'set' that overwrite all former values (duno if its necessary)
   - It looks like a "single value" but it's a list in the background.
2. Write custom methods

   Use custom methods like: def add_address(address), def clear_address(), get_address_all()

   What i don't like with this approach is:

   - It doesn't feel pythonic (may be this is more a feeling, than a fact)
3. Why the heck i think about it, just use the list directly as Interface.address

   What i don't like with this approach is:

   - It's not a simple list with strings but instances of IPv4Interface class. If my colleagues don't care about it, it could go worse.

May be somebody out here could get me some usefull hints or reason why to prefer one way over the other (or may be another one).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You change the interface to allow for a variable address count to be passed to the constructor.

```py
class Interface:
    def __init__(self, vlan, zone, *addresses):
        # ...

i = Interface(myVlan, myZone, myAddress1, myAddress2)
```

`addresses` becomes a tuple containing `myAddress1` and `myAddress1`. Alternatively, you could accept either an address object or a list of address objects and deal with the parameter according to its type. As for the address access, I would definitively go for option number 2. It's very flexible and easy to read, understand, and use.